# Is there a way in R to split a string in a column into multiple columns and add rows for every substring?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to achieve the following in R without using nested for loops:

```
input_df:                   output_df:
Attr1 Attr2 Dates           Attr1 Attr2 StartDate EndDate
1     2     A-B,B-C,D-E     1     2     A         B
3     4     F-G         --> 1     2     B         C
5     6     H-I,J-K         1     2     D         E
                            3     4     F         G
                            5     6     H         I
                            5     6     J         K
```

The dataframe has more than 50,000 rows and for loops take forever to get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows` with `separate`.  Split the 'Dates' column at the delimiter `,` and expand the rows with `separate_rows`, then with `separate`, split the 'Dates' into two column at the delimiter `-`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
separate_rows(input_df, Dates, sep = ",") %>%
     separate(Dates, into = c("StartDate", "EndDate"))
#  Attr1 Attr2 StartDate EndDate
#1     1     2         A       B
#2     1     2         B       C
#3     1     2         D       E
#4     3     4         F       G
#5     5     6         H       I
#6     5     6         J       K
```

---

Or another option is to extract the elements in to a `list` and then `unnest` the `list` column

```
library(stringr)
input_df %>%
  transmute(Attr1, Attr2, 
        StartDate = str_extract_all(Dates, "\\w+(?=-)"), 
        EndDate = str_extract_all(Dates, "(?<=-)\\w+")) %>% 
  unnest(c(StartDate, EndDate))
```

#### data

```
input_df <- structure(list(Attr1 = c(1L, 3L, 5L), Attr2 = c(2L, 4L, 6L), 
    Dates = c("A-B,B-C,D-E", "F-G", "H-I,J-K")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

With base R, you could do as follows. Split the Dates column by ',', then split the result again on '-' to create a two-column dataframe.

```
d <- strsplit(input_df$Dates, ',')
x <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(unlist(d), '-'))
```

Now you can repeat the original data's Attr1, Attr2 fields by as many components the splitting by ',' generated:

```
data.frame(input_df[rep(seq_len(NROW(input_df)), lengths(d)), 1:2], 
           Start = x[,1], 
           End = x[, 2])
# output
#    Attr1 Attr2 Start End
#1       1     2     A   B
#1.1     1     2     B   C
#1.2     1     2     D   E
#2       3     4     F   G
#3       5     6     H   I
#3.1     5     6     J   K
```

where input_df is defined below:

```
input_df <- data.frame(Attr1 = c(1L, 3L, 5L), 
                       Attr2 = c(2L, 4L, 6L), 
                       Dates = c("A-B,B-C,D-E", "F-G", "H-I,J-K"), 
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following code, where `substring` is used to extract the pairs in the third column:

```
res <- Reduce(rbind,
       lapply(split(input_df,seq(nrow(input_df))), function(v) {
         l <- nchar(v[3])
         data.frame(v[-3],
                    StartDate = substring(v[3],seq(1,l,4),seq(1,l,4)),
                    EndDate = substring(v[3],seq(3,l,4),seq(3,l,4)),
                    row.names = NULL)}
       )
)
```

**output**

```
> res
  Attr1 Attr2 StartDate EndDate
1     1     2         A       B
2     1     2         B       C
3     1     2         D       E
4     3     4         F       G
5     5     6         H       I
6     5     6         J       K
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` and first get data into long format and then in wide.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(cSplit(df, "Dates", direction = "long"), "Dates", sep = "-")

#   Attr1 Attr2 Dates_1 Dates_2
#1:     1     2       A       B
#2:     1     2       B       C
#3:     1     2       D       E
#4:     3     4       F       G
#5:     5     6       H       I
#6:     5     6       J       K
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Attr1 = c(1L, 3L, 5L), Attr2 = c(2L, 4L, 6L), 
Dates = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A-B,B-C,D-E", "F-G", "H-I,J-K"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```